# Running ADO Security Scanner without internet access and despite updated dependencies and .NET framework

Tags: azure-devops

How to run a ADO Security Scanner in an Agent which doesn't have internet access. What are the dependencies required to run the ADO security Scanner in an agent which doesn't have internet access.

when hv copied the required dependencies manually and updated the dotnet framework. but still getting the scanner is looking for internet access